kubernetes ingress address EMPTY, controller external-ip PENDING
I tried configuring ingress on my kubernetes cluster by using GCP Conpute Engine. I installed ingress-nginx and deployed 3 nginx:latest images:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      name: http

and following ingress.yaml
# nginx-ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: <my master node external ip>.nip.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-service
            port:
              number: 80


but there is no address at nginx-ingress
NAME            CLASS   HOSTS                  ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
nginx-ingress   nginx   "master-node-ip".nip.io             80      2d6h

also ingress-nginx-controller external-ip is pending for 2 days :(
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.108.188.48   <pending>     80:30412/TCP,443:30180/TCP   2d7h
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.97.140.213   <none>        443/TCP                      2d7h

